# algorithm is not working with some inputs

Tags: java

I'm new to programming, and I saw a problem in a website to practice. I was asked to create an algorithm that takes a positive integer, let's say *n*. If *n* is even the algorithm divides *n* by 2. If *n* is odd, it multiplies *n* by 3 and adds 1. This is repeated until it gets *n* = 1. For example,  *n*=3 the the output would be 3 > 10 > 5 > 16 > 8 > 4 > 2 > 1
My code looks like this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class practice {
    public static void solve(int n){
        while(n > 1){
            System.out.print(n + " ");
            if(n % 2 == 0){
                n=n/2;
            }else{
                n=(3*n)+1;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(n);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = keyboard.nextInt();
        solve(input);
    }
}
```

(Edit: Last output is suppose to be 1, but instead I'm getting random negative numbers with the next inputs):
138367
270271
665215
704511
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Why don't you log the values you go through in your loop, run with one of the numbers which doesn't work, and *find out* what the problem is?

Comment: Describe what "doesn't work" looks like.

Comment: It wasn't working as intended. The last output was supposed to be 1 but instead, I was getting negative random numbers, but my problem was solved, I had to use long instead of int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `int` is going out or range or out of bytes after some calculation try the given code using `long`:

```
import java.util.*;
public class practice {
    public static void solve(long n){
        while(n > 1){
            System.out.print(n + " ");
            if(n % 2 == 0){
                n=n/2;
            }else{
                n=(3*n)+1;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(n);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        long input = keyboard.nextLong();
        solve(input);
    }
}
```